# Storing SMS messages

Tags: python, class, typeerror

I realize this is a problem for which multiple solutions have been suggested on this forum, but I wrote a code and got an error that I don't understand, so that's mostly what I'm asking about here.

Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime

class SMSstore:
    store = []
    read = []
    unread =[]

    def addNewArrival(number,time,text):
        SMSstore.store.append(("From: {}, Recieved: {}, Msg: {}".format(number,time,text)))

    def messageCount():
        return print("Number of Messages in Inbox: {}".format(len(SMSstore.store)))

    def viewall():
      print(SMSstore.store)

    def getUnreadIndexes():
      for message in SMSstore.store:
            if message[0] == False:
                unread.append(self.__inbox.index(message))
      return unread

    def getMessage(i):
        SMSstore.read.append(len(SMSstore.store))
        print(SMSstore.store[i])

    def delete(i):
        try:
            del SMSstore.store[i]
        except IndexError:
            print("Index is out of range. Cannot delete")
    def clear():
        del SMSstore.store

time = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
myInbox = SMSstore()
myInbox.addNewArrival("1234567890",time,"What is your name?")
myInbox.addNewArrival("0987654321",time,"What is your quest?")
myInbox.viewall()
myInbox.msgcount()
myInbox.delete(i)
myInbox.clear()
```

The error I get is:

```
line 37, in <module>
TypeError: addNewArrival() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put self as the first arg in all the methods in a class.

Example:

```
def addNewArrival(self, number, time, text):
def messageCount(self):
def viewall(self):
```

More info [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: thanks for that! it appears to have fixed the problem, but now i get `line 29, in delete
TypeError: expected index value, got instance`

Comment: is something similar, inside the class you need to reference the class like **self**, so you need to do `self.store` or `self.read` or `self.unread`. You have more mistake as well, you need to define **i** to pass it like an arg and you are calling **messageCount** method with a wrong name